# Are $T$ and $T^{-1}$ bounded ? Yes/No

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

let $X$  be the normed  space whose  points are sequences  of complex number $x= (\xi_i)$ with only    finitely   many  nonzero terms and norm defined by $||x||=\sup_{i} |\xi_i|$.Let $T : X \to X$ be defined by $$y=Tx =(\xi_1,\frac{1}{2}\xi_2 ,\frac{1}{3}\xi_3,.....)$$

Then  choose  the correct option

$1.$  $T$ is bounded

$2.T^{-1}$ is bounded

$3.T$ is unbounded

$4.T^{-1}$ is unbounded

**My attempt** :$$||Tx|| = \sup_{j\ge 1} \frac{|\xi_j|}{j}\le ||x||\sup_{j \ge 1}\frac1j\le ||x||$$

$$\implies ||T(x)|| \le ||x||$$ for all $x \in X$

Therefore $T$  is bounded.  So option $1$  is correct

Since$\|T\|^{-1} \leq \|T^{-1}\|$ so we have  $$ ||T(x)|| \le ||x|| \implies  ||T^{-1}(x)||\le ||x||$$

Therefore $T^{-1}$  is bounded.

**My answer**  : 0ption $1$ and   $2$ are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T^{-1}(\xi_1,\xi_2,...)=(\xi_1, 2\xi_2,3\xi_3,...)$. If $e_n$ has $1$ in the $n-th$ place and $0$ elsewhere then $Te_n=ne_n$ so $\|Te_n\|=n\|e_n\|$. This proves that $T^{-1}$ is unbounded.